# Need to update the Destination table when Source tables updates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I have a report which uses some `tables` with large data. We Wrote a stored procedure to get the required data from the `tables` and prcoess the report output `table`. Since the data volume is large, we dont want to call the procedure to call entire source `tables` data whenever any updates happened in them. We need to update only the `'updated/changed rows`in source table      into destination`table`.

what is best way to do this in `Sql Server`?

Thanks for the Help.

Answer (score 0):

You can definetely use table triggers
Please check [SQL Server Trigger Example to Log Changes](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-trigger-sql-server-trigger-example-to-log-changes-history.aspx)

There is also a solution called **CDC (Change Data Capture)** in SQL Server
You can also investigate CDC

Comment: Which one is good in terms of performance? Also,Using CDC can we directly update the changes to destination table as like triggers.  thanks

Comment: I did not actually used CDC, but you're more flexible with triggers. On the other hand, each time a data is updated it means an other insert is executing behind. So insert time will increase any how. And if you decide using a trigger use SET based logic, otherwise as many developers do without realizing your trigger will work false